# Oracle 11.2 index on VARCHAR vs index on DATE

Tags: oracle, index, oracle-11g-r2, varchar, date-format

I have a table with 15,339,375 records and it has an index on a date field that's converted to a `VARCHAR(5)` and stored as `"MMYDD"`.  It has an index on the field.  The records in the table are all from 2015.

When I run a `count(fieldname)` against the table for all records `BETWEEN '01501' AND '12531'` it returns`15,339,375` in 92 seconds.

Now I copied this table, converted the date field to an actual date, and created an index on the field.  When I run the same query for the range `BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE('12/31/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY')` the query never completes and I have to kill it after an hour or so.  Running the query for just January and February takes 88 seconds the first time and 2.9 seconds the second time.

Now why would an index on a `VARCHAR(5)` field be more efficient than an index on a DATE field?  Also why would the query run faster the second time?

Comment: Can you post exact query ?  In particular, what is the value of "fieldname".  I'm speculating, but if you used to write`count(indexed_string_field) where indexed_string_field between ...` and then replaced it with `count(indexed_string_field) where indexed_new_Date_field between ...`  , then you changed execution plan from index range scan or index seek to most likely full table scan

Comment: Also, can you post the syntax of the index?

Comment: Second time is faster probably because you are selecting the same rows again expecting the same result so blocks are still in memory.

Comment: `char(5)` would be a better choice than `varchar(5)`.  It's a waste of space to keep the length in each data row if it's always fixed (coming from SQL Server, but I believe the same is true in Oracle).

Comment: @ArinTaylor The same is not true in Oracle.  In Oracle char is just a varchar2 that is blank padded (when necessary), so in this case the space usage and performance would be identical.  I recommend never using char in Oracle because it is never superior and is often inferior (but identical in this case).  See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2668391900346844476

Comment: @Leigh Riffel Thanks, that was an interesting read!  I wasn't aware oracle uses the length byte(s) as the null indicator as well, which makes it make more sense as to why that's the implementation.

Comment: @regmar To do a true filter for dates between '01501' and '12531' you would have to convert these values back from characters to dates, otherwise the range would include dates such as '11609', '10908', AND '09317' which are within the character range but not the date range.

Comment: Get an execution plan of the query. Since the query does not complete, let it run for 10s or so, cancel it, and then run:  select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor( null, null, 'TYPICAL' ) );